# Ways to learning basics of Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I am pretty new to ML and doing below things to learn more about it:

```
1. Subscribed to ML emails through which I can learn.
2. Went to YouTube and ML-Dev-Area and viewing some of the available videos.
3. Reading Java-ML-Communication PDF's from ML-Website.
```

Is there any other basic tutorials/videos/free-e-books available using which I can get good basic understanding of ML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[DMC](http://developer.marklogic.com) is a very good starting point for any information about MarkLogic. There are interactive tutorials, blogs, videos, all kinds of resources as well as extensive documentation.

To start with basics, go to the home page, and watch the 5-minuten video tutorials. After that, go to the [Tutorials section](http://developer.marklogic.com/learn). There are references to the interactive tutorials, and more.

The [Blog section](http://developer.marklogic.com/blog) is also very interesting if you need help on something specific, without digging into the full documentation. Make sure to check out the blogroll as well, there are quite some blogs outside DMC with interesting stories about MarkLogic.

Also, MarkLogic just recently announced to provide various free online trainings. You can find those here:

http://developer.marklogic.com/learn/free-online-training

HTH!

Comment: Grtjn -- Thanks for posting response. I was checking on youtube for ML videos, but didn't found video that contains detailed analysis. Your post contains very useful information. Currently I don't have upvote rights cause I am new, so want to say -- Thank you -- and would like to know what is HTH means :)

Comment: @NikhilJoshi: HTH stands for Hope That Helps.. ;-)

Comment: @NikhilJoshi Though, I can't stop reading it as Hi The Ho, which sounds like a friendly greeting in some yet undiscovered language.. :-P